# WordPress deactivate a plugin via database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress script, wp-supercache, that I need to disable (as its cached on a nasty error), however, the error is causing the wp-admin redirect to fail, which means I can't get into the site to disable the plugin.

Any advice? I can access the database via cpanel.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try re-naming the folder of the plugin and then see if error is gone (make backup first of course.). If that does not help, **[here is the solution](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/02/18/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/)** then.

Comment: Deleting the plugins folder is too much. Just rename it, as stated on the answer below this one.

Answer (score 24):

To disable a specific plugin, you have to remove it from the serialized string that stores the list of all plugins - that's set in the `option_value` column of the `wp_options` table as discussed by @TimDurden. The specific format change you have to make is, [taken shamelessly from teh Internet](http://blog.projectnibble.org/2011/07/22/quickly-disable-a-wordpress-plugin-via-the-database/):

```
a:4:{
    i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";
    i:1;s:36:"google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.php";
    i:2;s:55:"google-syntax-highlighter/google_syntax_highlighter.php";
    i:3;s:29:"wp-swfobject/wp-swfobject.php";
}
```

That first set of characters - `a:4` - designates an array and its length. Note also that each line in the list of plugins has an index. So:

1. Decrement the index (from 4 to 3 in this case)
2. In each line, decrement the number after the `i:`
3. Remove the specific plugin you want to disable.

Update the value in the db using the new string you constructed from these steps:

```
update wp_options set option_value=<new value> where option_id=<id of this option>
```

Note that your table name might not be wp_options - you might have a prefix to add.

Answer (score 14):

You only need to rename the folder in /wp-content/plugins/ and the plugin will be automatically de-activated. Once it is de-activated, you will be able to login.

Comment: This worked fine for me..i installed captcha plugin and could not get into admin area...I just went to file manager and renamed the plugin folder name...And the plugin got deactivated

Comment: This will work in most scenarios however, sometimes a plugin will make changes that only get rolled back when uninstalling via the UI.. ie using the [register_uninstall_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook).

Comment: @StevendeSalas: The question was about how to disable a plugin that broke the admin UI. If they are not able to log into the UI, they will not be able to use it to uninstall the plugin.

Answer (score 7):

1. Backup database or just the wp_options table
2. > SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
3. Copy selected string (serialized string) and paste in the left side at https://serializededitor.com/
4. Remove the line which plugin you want to deactivate
5. Copy the serialized result string from the right side and update active_plugins value with it.

   > UPDATE wp_options
   >   SET option_value = 'THE_NEW_SERIALIZED_STRING'
   >   WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins' LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little exe in .dot to repair/remove options string from database.

1. Download exe [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19179569/ParseWordPressPlugins.zip)
2. Run on MySQL server

> SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';

3. Paste Results in textbox, press parse.
4. Remove the ones you don't want.
5. Click output, it copies output to clipboard
6. replace brackets inside the single quotes below with output and Run on MySQL server

> UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '[replace inside single quotes with your output' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';

6. No warranties... I don't claim to be programmer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To disable all Wordpress plugins on your site:

1. Login to your database management tool (e.g. PHPMyAdmin)
2. Execute the following query:

`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';`

Comment: This works for WordPress 2.9 and back. For versions newer than 2.9 the correct SQL is `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';` as it is mentioned here http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is you can backup the site and then just rename the folder of the plugin under /wp-content/plugins/ to some other name . So the plugin will be disabled.
I wont prefer deleting the plugin folder as it may cause errors.
After the step is done log in to your wordpress site and delete the plugin from there

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the values in the record "active_plugins" in the database. You can find the process [Here](https://www.indusmagazine.com/tutorials/reset-wordpress-plugins-via-database-directly/)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer,but answering as it will be useful to someone in the future. All the plugins are stored in the wp_options table in a serialized manner. U can edit this field manually. Or if you unserialize it using a function like in php using unserialize(), you will get an array. just modify it to remove the plugin you want to remove from that array, and serialize it back. then update the table. Thats it. If you want to know more about it [here](http://bitmapcake.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-disable-wordpress-plugins-manually.html) is a good article. It explains all about this.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can activate your plugin from the `functions.php`:

```
function activate_plugin_via_php() {
    $active_plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
    array_push($active_plugins, 'unyson/unyson.php'); /* Here just replace unyson plugin directory and plugin file*/
    update_option( 'active_plugins', $active_plugins );
}
add_action( 'init', 'activate_plugin_via_php' );
```

Comment: **Guidlunes for you**

`unyson :- It's plugin folder name
 unyson.php :- Plugin main file
If you would like to activate more than one plugin at one time
Then just repeat array_push($active_plugins, 'unyson/unyson.php');
With plugin folder name and php file.`