# Does wordpress save plugin/theme version info in database?

Tags: wordpress

I lost all files of my wordpress website, but I have the database.

In it, there is a list of the plugins and themes. But I can't find any version info for these.

Does wp keep the version of the installed plugins/themes in sql database? Perhaps it's encoded somehow?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress deactivate a plugin via database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624551/wordpress-deactivate-a-plugin-via-database) - this shows you how and where the plugins are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless you have a plugin that tracked your updates and versions;

All version numbers are stored in the plugins themselves part of the docblock metadata, this is so updates go smoothly and don't conflict with the database; if you copy the plugsins into wp-content/plugins most(repuitable) plugsin will attempt to process an update.

sorry I couldnt be more help

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress save the theme and plugin details like active theme name, active plugin name.
You can find these details in wp_options table in database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).